# MongoDB vs RethinkDB

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, rethinkdb

Занимаюсь разработкой реал-тайм приложения в моем случае это онлайн игра. Стал вопрос, что использовать лучше MongoDB или RethinkDB? Прежде не имел дела с реал-тайм базами данных такими как RethinkDB или Firebase. В MongoDB при входе игрока я загружаю информацию о пользователе в массив всех игроков и обрабатываю как мне это необходимо, если игрок запрашивает информацию я посылаю ему ее из массива(скорость на лицо), после выхода игрока, вся информация записывается в бд и удаляется с массива. Как производить это с RethinkDB, как говорится база данных использует сокеты значит ли это, что я могу вместо массива постоянно делать запросы в бд, а не хранить информацию в RAM и на сколько это практично в плане скорости? Суть в том, что мне необходимо обрабатывать миллиарды записей(игровые чанки) и подгружать их по мере продвижения игрока по миру. С RethinkDB могу ли я делать прямые запросы в бд каждый раз когда игрок движется или же стоит создавать пулы, загружать их в массивы и уже с массивов посылать клиенту информацию а затем через определенное время выгружать(чистить RAM)?
Как такое лучше реализовать и на какой DB?

Comment: Если вам дам исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

> Как производить это с RethinkDB, как говорится база данных использует
>   сокеты

Так же, как и MongoDB.

> значит ли это, что я могу вместо массива постоянно делать запросы в
>   бд, а не хранить информацию в RAM и на сколько это практично в плане
>   скорости

Я не понимаю, в чём разница. Что там, что там на низшем уровне используются сокеты. Вы можете и там, и там загружать эти данные в массив и работать с ним, а в базу потом писать изменения.

> С RethinkDB могу ли я делать прямые запросы в бд каждый раз когда
>   игрок движется или же стоит создавать пулы, загружать их в массивы и
>   уже с массивов посылать клиенту информацию а затем через определенное
>   время выгружать(чистить RAM)? Как такое лучше реализовать и на какой
>   DB?

Работа с RethinkDB, повторюсь, ничем не отличается от Монги. Но...

1. Каждый раз новый запрос посылать имеет смысл только если эти данные могут менять больше одного игрока.
2. Каждый раз новый запрос посылать имеет смысл только если у вас есть реплики. Я надеюсь, вы не держите всего одну ноду с базой и вашим сервисом с массивом. То есть, по-хорошему, у вас как минимум 3 ноды в реплике. На каждом ноду у вас сервис, в котором вы кешируете массив. Теперь возникает проблема рассинхронизации экземпляров ваших массивов. Теперь вам либо их синхронить, либо при заходе игрока закреплять его за конкретным сервером, к которому будут идти запросы, чтоб грязных данных из инвалидного кеша не получить. Но, опять же, по-хорошему, API сервер и сервер с БД - это разные машины обычно. Так что, инфу о том с какого сервака брать данные нужно как-то прокидывать. Обычно это делается назначением умного id записи в БД, чтоб по нему потом смотреть, куда стучаться в праймари реплику за данными.

Это я к чему, если у вас прототип с одной нодой, то массив в памяти - ок решение, если нод несколько, то, что с Ресинком, что с Монгой в случае с использованием массива будут проблемы.

**UPD:** если решили использовать Ресинк, то нужно использовать его основную фичу - [подписку на изменения](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/). Ваш сервис на серваке подписывается на изменения записи в БД. Если кто-то поменяет её, то ваш сервис узнает об этом и обновит данные в массиве. Это устраняет проблемы с синхронизацией массивов между нодами. Так что, алгоритм такой:

1. Клиент (игрок) стучится к сервису.
2. Сервис смотрит, есть ли в массиве запись по этому игроку.

   1. Если нет.

      1. Грузит данные.
      2. Подписывается на изменения и обновляет данные в массиве по мере необходимости.
   2. Если есть, отдаётся клиенту.
3. При необходимости внести изменения, клиент отправляет запрос к сервису, тот обновляет в базе данные. В массиве можно сейчас и не обновлять, т.к. подписка вам всё равно эти изменения вернёт, тогда уже можно будет и обновить.
4. Если игрок ушёл оффлайн, удаляем записать из массива.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, однако сам вопрос состоит в том, что стоит ли использовать промежуточный массив в памяти в случае работы с RethinkDB или можно обойтись без него и делать запросы сразу в RethinkDB? Судя по описанию реал-тайм баз данных каждый клиент хранит часть информации с бд у себя, сравнивает с новой информацией и уже решает обновлять или нет. Если же с реал-тайм базой данных я должен сперва выгружать информацию в массив, а потом отправлять клиенту, то я не вижу преимуществ использовать данную бд.

Comment: @user290812 сейчас допишу ответ

Comment: @user290812 обновил ответ.

Comment: стоит еще написать, что разработка rethink уже не ведется, этот факт играет некоторую роль в принятии решений

Comment: @etki ну...формально ведётся, только силами сообщества.